# Inconsistent behaviour ReWrite rules in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, sitemap

I have a test and live sever for my website. Both use the same ReWrite rule in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ - [L] 
RewriteRule ^sitemap(.*)$ /php/nl/sitemap.php$1
```

Live server works as espected, but test server fails

When changing "sitemap" to "sitemaptest" is works like a charm.

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ - [L] 
RewriteRule ^sitemaptest(.*)$ /php/nl/sitemap.php$1
```

Puzzled.... Related to apache version inconsistency? Anyone?

Comment: What do you mean saying "test server fails"?

Comment: This means that the test server displays the 404 (not found) page. FYI the files on the test server are equal to the live server.

Comment: I suggest you to enable [RewriteLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) for verbose logging and look, what's actually going on.